# Django CKEDITOR, Image Upload path different with ImageField upload path

Tags: python, django, django-models, ckeditor, imagefield

I'm using django-ckeditor to load images.I can't merger my image upload path in model with django-ckeditor image upload path.

I have already created a upload image path in models:

```
content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="news/%Y/%m")
```

In order to merger it with django-ckeditor,I set this in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'news/%Y/%m'
```

But although the image upload through django-ckeditor will also be in news directory,however the path will be different from the image that upload through models.ImageField.They both are in news directory but in two different sub directories.

Is there any way that can merger the two path into one?